# Cookies memory problems in javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am using `createcookie` and `getcookie` functions to save my values in cookies.

What I am doing is just calling `createcookie(name,value,days)` function and setting my value. When my value gets updated from somewhere, I call again `createcookie(name,value,days)` with the same parameters of 'name' and 'days'.

Now my question is that will it fill up all cookie memory by doing this (overwriting previous cookie with newer one) or not?

Comment: it will overwrite your old coockie.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `createCookie` with the name of an existing cookie will replace the value of that cookie. As [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) says:

> With JavaScript, you can change a cookie the same way as you create it:
>
> `document.cookie = "username=John Smith; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 >UTC; path=/";`
>
> The old cookie is overwritten.

If you'd like to add more data to a cookie without erasing the cookie, you could set the value of the cookie to the original value plus a new value, i.e. 
`setcookie("myCookie",getCookie('myCookie') + newData, date))`